# Informing connections on LinkedIn about looking for new opportunities?

Tags: job-search, linkedin

So, I've given notice to my current employer, but have to work off my 3 month notice period fully. I've sent emails to a few recruiters I'm connected to on LinkedIn, but would like to publicize this to everyone. I'm thinking of posting something like this:

```
After a fantastic year at Company X, it's time to move on to new challenges.
Willing to relocate for work, but do need visa sponsorship. Available to start
in March. Please like or share.
```

How does it read?

Comment: I would change "please like or share" to something less meta and slightly more professional, such as "please spread the word" or "Introductions appreciated" which mean pretty much the same thing but are less social-media-y

Comment: @KateGregory But LinkedIn is social media.  http://www.linkedintraining.net/share-and-share-alike-on-linkedin/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My Suggestion would be:

> After a fantastic year at Company X as a **{position}**, I am looking for
>   my next future challenge in **{Area of expertise or may be a different path}**. Willing to relocate
>   for work, but do need visa sponsorship. Available to start in March.
>   Please like or share.

In the same time it is also very good to update `Your professional headline` with something close.

Comment: In the end, I went with: `Looking to explore challenging new opportunities in the Data Science domain. Willing to relocate, but visa sponsorship required. Introductions and likes/shares appreciated!`

Comment: That does look nice!  If I may say so, I'd be very happy to hear of something positive came up for you. I'm in the same position. I updated my LinkedIn headline, but I guess posting might help. One thing though: you could join a data science (job) group, and post it there.

Answer (score -1):

This looks insincere and very facebook-like.  Something like this can be good:

> Looking for (exciting <-- this is optional) opportunities in the _______ domain. Have ___ years of
>   experience at < XYZ >.
>
> Willing to relocate. Would require visa sponsorship.

Comment: But LinkIn is FaceBook like.  Pretty sure OP means posting IN LinkedIn.  The domain and years of experience is in LinkedIn.

Comment: @Frisbee  Yes, you are right. But, I think LinkedIn needs more professional-istic posting, as opposed to Facebook.  So, the OP's post looks more like the Facebook type ones, so I suggested a bit more professional looking post :)

Comment: Professional to repeat what is already already in your profile?  You missed the question and are just trying to cover.  You eliminated the key action "like or share".  Those ARE the terms used by by LinkedIn.   If it is FB like then so be it - that is reality.

Comment: @Frisbee I didn't miss the question :)  I've already mentioned in the answer that the post looks unprofessional to me.  Just a **Looking for exciting/interesting opportunities**, it would be better to include maximum details in the shortest way possible.   Just a _Looking for an opportunity in ____ domain_ would interest a recruiter, unless and until they know details about the profile, which can make them have a look into it.

Comment: He wants them to Like and Share and you leave that off.  You leave off the objective.

Comment: @Frisbee Yeah, maybe my mistake that _like and share_ felt too informal.    I guess, I'm wrong.  :)

Comment: Share is a formal action he wants them to take  https://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/518/kw/share